# Window background image looks weird around label (PyQt5)

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt5

I created a window and added a background image to it. I also added a label to be in the center of the window, my problem is that there is a weird box around the label like as if it has sort of a weird background color.

I tried to fix it using this line of code:
`headline.setStyleSheet("background-color: transparent;")`
but it doesn't change anything.

Here is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDesktopWidget, QWidget, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont

BACKGROUND_IMAGE_PATH = "./documents/background_image.jpg"


def setWidgets(window: QWidget, window_geo: list):
    # Create the headline text
    headline = QLabel(window)
    headline.setText("A big label here")

    font = QFont("Times New Roman")
    # Set font size to 60% of the window height
    font.setPointSize(int(window_geo[3] * 0.06))

    # Set the background color of the label to transparent
    headline.setStyleSheet("QLabel {\n"
                           "    background-color: transparent;\n"
                           "}")

    headline.setFont(font)
    headline.adjustSize()
    headline.move((window_geo[2] - headline.width()) // 2,
                  window_geo[1] + window_geo[3] // 5 - headline.height() // 2)


def getWindowValues():
    """
    getWindowValues getting the screen (width and height) and reduce it by 25 present to set the size of the app window
    """
    desktop = QDesktopWidget()
    screen_width = desktop.screenGeometry().width()
    screen_height = desktop.screenGeometry().height()

    window_width = int(screen_width * 0.75)
    window_height = int(screen_height * 0.80)

    # setting the x and y to be in the middle of the screen
    x = int(((screen_width - window_width) / 2) * 0.1)
    y = int((screen_height - window_height) / 2)

    return x, y, window_width, window_height


def main():
    stylesheet = f"QWidget {{background-image: url('{BACKGROUND_IMAGE_PATH}'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center;}}"

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)

    # getting the geometry of the window
    x, y, window_width, window_height = getWindowValues()

    window = QWidget()
    window.setWindowTitle("App name")

    setWidgets(window, [x, y, window_width, window_height])

    window.setGeometry(x, y, window_width, window_height)
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is a picture of the output:

[image: screenshot resulting from the code]

Answer (score 1):

QWidget is the base class of all user interface objects in Qt. All widgets inherit from it.

If you set an application wide stylesheet that uses the `QWidget` type selector, the result is that **all** widgets (no matter their type) will use the properties set for it.

The "weird background" you see is the portion of the image used in the QApplication stylesheet (cropped to geometry of the label), and you can see it because `background-image` is drawn *above* the background color, allowing the background to be visible in case the image has an alpha channel; since your image is opaque, the background is not "visible" and the `transparent` color is ignored anyway.

If you look more closely, you'll see that the background of the label is actually the portion of the background image that is at the center of it (since you used `background-position: center`):

[image: original background showing the cropped selection]

<sup>The selection is slightly off, you are probably using an image with a different cropping.</sup>

This is the reason for which `QWidget` alone should *never* be used as a QSS type selector for parent widgets, composite/complex widgets or the application.

Similarly, you shall not use the `*` selector or generic properties without selectors, unless you know what you're doing: while `QApplication.setStyleSheet()` always requires explicit selectors, it's possible to use generic properties for `QWidget.setStyleSheet()`, but that should always be done only for *basic* widgets (labels, buttons, pure QWidgets); doing that for complex widgets (like QComboBox or QScrollArea) will make *all* components of the widget use those properties, and will possibly make the widget appearance quite odd, because many widgets require that even if *one* property is set, *all* the other must be set along with it.

If you want to set a specific background for that `window` widget, then you either set the stylesheet to it (`window.setStyleSheet()`), or use a proper selector. The common convention is to use the object name:

```py
    stylesheet = f"QWidget#myWindow {{ background-image: etc... }}"
                          ^^^^^^^^^

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)

    # getting the geometry of the window
    x, y, window_width, window_height = getWindowValues()

    window = QWidget()
    window.setObjectName("myWindow")

    # Qt properties can also be set in the object constructor,
    # using keyword arguments:
    # window = QWidget(objectName="myWindow")
    ...
```

If you're using *pure* QWidgets (not subclasses) as windows and you want to avoid using the same object name (which is not strictly forbidden, but discouraged for "sibling" objects), you can also use the dot class selector:

```py
    stylesheet = f".QWidget {{ background-image: etc... }}"
                  ^^^
```

Final notes:

- QDesktopWidget is deprecated, use [`QScreen`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html) instead;
- while it may work fine for simple cases, using a functional programming pattern in Qt has lots of limitations, mostly because it requires continuous declarations of objects and often brings to bad habits or practices (like using globals to work around problems); sooner or later you'll be forced to use an object oriented programming pattern anyway (using subclasses), so I strongly suggest you to start to familiarize with that;
- it's **label**, not "lable";

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the background color of the label to be transparent:

```
headline.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);")
```

2. Set the autoFillBackground property of the label to False:

```
headline.setAutoFillBackground(False)
```

Comment: I tried it now and it did't work, I updated my code in the quistion please consider check the updated code

Comment: The code is fine @roee, however, with complex images, there is warping around the QLabel object. But with solid colors, it works fine.